# Retrieving the Admin Email in ZenCart's Backend

Tags: php, backend, zen-cart

I have the following code present in my script. It's using the ZenCart built in DB Query handler. It's supposed to be pulling up the admin email address of the current admin.

Is there a better way to pull up the email address?
All of this is being run from a script in ZenCart's backend.

```
$query = "select admin_email from ". TABLE_ADMIN ." where admin_id = " . $_SESSION['admin_id'];
$admin = $db->Execute( $query );
if( $admin ) {    $admin = $admin->fields;  }

  zen_mail($customer['customers_firstname'] . " " . $customer['customers_lastname'],
       $customer['customers_email_address'],
       $subject,
       $text,
       TITLE,
       $admin['admin_email'],
       $block,
       $module_used
     );
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Is there a better way to pull up the email?". If the email is stored in the database the only way to retrieve it is to "pull" it from the database.

Comment: well I generally mean that when I use try to retrieve I normally get an error or "Cannot convert queryFactoryResult to string" or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general purpose access to cart-sent email, use the Email Archive Manager:

http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=101

If you're writing custom code, and need to grab the current admin's email address, do something like this:

```
  $admin_id = $_SESSION['admin_id'];
  $addr_query = "SELECT admin_email FROM " . TABLE_ADMIN . " WHERE admin_id = :a
dmin_id"; 
  $addr_query = $db->bindVars($addr_query, ':admin_id', $admin_id, 'integer');
  $addr_query_result =  $db->Execute($addr_query);
  echo "***" . $addr_query_result->fields['admin_email'];
```

Comment: I need the address NOT the specific emails.

Comment: Updated my answer - I misunderstood your objective.